# php mail / submit a variable span

Tags: html, forms, post, php

I am trying to submit a `<span>` value to be mailed through php.

I want to submit the variable span `res1`:

```
<form method="POST" name="results" action="message.php">
      <span id="res1">Mail This:*this part varies*</span>
</form>
```

using this handler:

```
$body .= $_REQUEST['#res1']." \n";
mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
```

I'd prefer for the `<span>` to not be in the form; i'm not sure if this is possible though?

Excuse my ignorance - never worked with server side stuff before! Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does *this part varies* get to the span? Use the same instruction to add a

```
<input type="hidden" name="res1" value="the same value you put in the span"/>
```

Then, in your PHP code you can get the value with `$_REQUEST['res1']` or `$_POST['res1']` -- note the removed hash.

**Update**

For anybody who might make a similar mistake, here is what would work and what wouldn't.

HTML forms only send the values of form controls when submitted. They are:

- `input`s of various types (`text`, `password`, `radio`, `checkbox`, `hidden`, `file`, `submit`, `image`, or newer HTML5 inputs like `email`, etc.)
- `select`s
- `textarea`s

Furthermore, the value of an input is only submitted if it has been assigned a `name`. So if the following inputs are in a form, on submitting the form whatever value *bugs* may have will be submitted, but nothing will be submitted for *bunny*:

```
<input type="text" name="bugs"/>
<input type="text" id="bunny"/>
```

So, putting any element between `<form> ... </form>` does not cause the text inside it to be  submitted. For a value to be submitted it should be one of the above form controls AND it should have a `name` property set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

```
<form method="POST" name="results" action="message.php">
  <input type="hidden" id="res1" value="some text" />
</form>
```

You can use javascript to access and change "res1"

```
document.getElementById("res1").value=some variable or textbox content;
```